# list option in html from text files

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to list options in drop down menu in HTML form but i need to make some options to be multiline .and the options i need to read them from text file.any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Why a dropdown then? Use radiobuttons if you want multiline. You can style the radiobuttons, or put them in an overflow: scroll save space.

Comment: Ok.i may use radio buttons ,but how to put them in an overflow: scroll save space.also how to save them in file and read every multiline option ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your HTML display values from a text file, you're going to need to use some kind of server-side generation (ASP.NET, JSP, CGI, whatever).  The exact solution will depend on what server-side technology you use/choose, but in all cases it should be fairly straightforward as this is a common requirement for all of these technologies.

As for your first part, what *exactly* do you mean by "some options to be multiline"?  Do you mean that some values are quite long and have spaces, so you want them to wrap?  Do you want to have some kind of drop-down box that shows multiple values at once?  Do you want them not to be a dropdown at all?  How will you decide between the values that should be multiline and those that should not?  If you can express your intention more clearly (which may involve some additional thinking on your end), it will be possible to help, and you may even end up working out the solution yourself.

Comment: I get the option of the list from user using text area which is multiline , and i save the option to files .and then read them back to the user list , i want as u said "drop-down box that shows multiple values at once". and Im using JSP.